# Vimeo Video Inside Bootstrap embed-responsive-16by9 Container Creates White Space Above and Below

Tags: vimeo

I'm integrating a Vimeo video into my webpage using the Salesforce's SiteGenesis framework with ISML templates. I've managed to get the video to occupy the full width of its container, but there's unintended white space above and below the video.

Here's my HTML structure:

```
<div class="video-banner-full-width">
    <div class="video-content-full-width">
        <div class="video-text-overlay">
            <!-- Some Text Content -->
        </div>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?&amp;parameters"></iframe>
            <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By default, the iframe from Vimeo comes with inline styles: style="max-width: calc(143.148vh); height: calc(69.8577vw);". To achieve full width, I used the embed-responsive-16by9 class from Bootstrap. This addressed the width issue, but introduced white spaces on the top and bottom.

To counteract this, I tried changing the embed-responsive position to static among other styles, but the white spaces still remain.

I've tried:

Overriding styles with CSS (including !important).
Using JavaScript to modify the inline styles after the video is loaded.
Changing the embed-responsive position to static and adjusting other styles.
But still, the issue persists.

website: https://bfqs-002.dx.commercecloud.salesforce.com/s/unode50_eu/home?lang=es_ES

Comment: website: https://bfqs-002.dx.commercecloud.salesforce.com/s/unode50_eu/home?lang=es_ES